# Start Android 4.3 (API 18) when minSdk = 19

Tags: android

I have application with **minSdkVersion 19** (Android 4.4).
Also I have Android device with **Android 4.3 (API 18)**. As result Android Studio not run application on this device.

I know that if I decrement **minSdkVersion**  to **18** the application will success run on my  device. But I can't do this, because it's client requerments - **minSdkVersion 19**.

So the question is:

Is it possible to start application with **minSdkVersion 19** on device with **Android 4.3 (API 18)** ?

Comment: no you can't, that's the point of minSdkVersion

Comment: however, you can make the minSdkVersion 18 during development and change it to 19 when commiting/releasing

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, but if your app is running on API level 18, I'm sure your client will not object against it - gives him a few more possible users for the app.